# OpenCL 2.0 - Error: function "work_group_reduce_add" declared implicitly

Tags: c, opencl

I have an issue at the execution of a OpenCL code (compiled with AMD-APP SDK v3.0) with the following kernel code :

```
__kernel void sumGPU ( __global const int *input, 
                        __global int *sum )
 {
  uint local_id = get_local_id(0);
  uint group_size = get_local_size(0);
  uint global_id = get_global_id(0);

  uint res = input[global_id];        

  // workgroup reduction (introduced in OpenCL 2.0)
  res = work_group_reduce_add(res);

  // atomic reduce in global memory
  if (local_id == 0)
    atomic_add(sum, res);
 }
```

This is for computing the summation of all array elements.

I get the following error :

```
CL Compilation failed:
"/tmp/OCL32344T1.cl", line 11: error: function "work_group_reduce_add"
          declared implicitly
    res = work_group_reduce_add(res);
          ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/OCL32344T1.cl".
Frontend phase failed compilation.
Aborted
```

It seems that prototype of work_group_reduce_add is missing but I can't find it into OpenCL 2.0 (CL/cl.h).

Anyone could see what's wrong ? Thanks

Comment: No idea why this is getting downvotes, there's no way to magically know that you need to do something special to get 2.0 to work like the accepted answer tells you to. Just had the same problem, thanks for asking this question because it ultimately saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use OpenCL 2.0 functionality in your kernels, you need to pass the `-cl-std=CL2.0` flag to the compiler via `clBuildProgram`.

Comment: Thanks, above error has disappeared but another happens at the execution : "CL Compilation failed:
Error: aclBinary init failure
Aborted"
Any idea ?

Comment: From https://community.amd.com/message/1306688#1306688, do I have to conclude that my Radeon HD 7970 is not supported for OpenCL 2.0 ?

Comment: Yes, that's likely the reason. You can query whether your device supports OpenCL 2.0 by using `clGetDeviceInfo` and the `CL_DEVICE_VERSION` and `CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION` flags.